# How to add QLabel on QTreeWidgetItem qt c++?

Tags: c++, qt

I want insert a QLabel with a icon  into QTreeWidgetItem but i can't find any way to do this.

This is the child Function:

```
void MainWindow::addChildServer(QTreeWidgetItem *parent, QString child)
{
    QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem();
    item->setText(0,child);
    item->setTextAlignment(0,Qt::AlignVCenter);

    QPixmap pxm(":/logo/resources/icon.png");
    pxm = pxm.scaled(QSize(15, 15), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    QFont fnt;
    fnt.setPixelSize(15);
    item->setFont(0,fnt);
    item->setIcon(0,pxm);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel();

    label->resize(10,10);

    QPixmap pix(":/logo/resources/logo.png");
    pix = pix.scaled(label->size(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio);

    label->setPixmap(pix);
    label->setAccessibleName(name);
    label->setStyleSheet("margin-left:200px");
    label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight);



    ui->treeWidget->setItemWidget(item,0,label);
    parent->addChild(item);


}
```

The QLabel is not added.

Comment: Why are you setting `QLabel` on an item in treeWidget? What is wrong with default behavior? Did you read documentation of [QTreeWidget::setItemWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtreewidget.html#setItemWidget)?

Comment: I need a icon on right side of the child item.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtreewidgetitem.html#setIcon